# Update files in Phonegap file api and remove unused files

Tags: android, file, cordova

I'm using Phonegap's file api for the data of my app. Downloading files is no problem, however I don't know how to update the files or remove unused ones. Here's my code:

```
var DATADIR;
var knownfiles = [];    

function onFSSuccess(fileSystem) {
fileSystem.root.getDirectory("Android/data/be.emm.mobile",
{create:true},gotDir,onError);
}

function gotDir(d){
console.log("got dir");
DATADIR = d;
var reader = DATADIR.createReader();
reader.readEntries(function(d){
    gotFiles(d);
    appReady();
},onError);
}

function gotFiles(entries) {
console.log("The dir has "+entries.length+" entries.");
for (var i=0; i<entries.length; i++) {
console.log(entries[i].name+' dir? '+entries[i].isDirectory);
    knownfiles.push(entries[i].name);
    }
}

function onError(e){
console.log("ERROR");
console.log(JSON.stringify(e));
}

 function onDeviceReady() {
$("#status").html("Checking your local cache....");    
window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, onFSSuccess, null);    
}

function appReady(){
$("#status").html("Ready to check remote files...");
$.get("http://mllsdemode.be/EMM-test/download.json", {}, function(res) {
    if (res.length > 0) {
        $("#status").html("Going to sync some images...");
        for (var i = 0; i < res.length; i++) {
            if (knownfiles.indexOf(res[i]) == -1) {
                console.log("need to download " + res[i]);
                var ft = new FileTransfer();
                var dlPath = DATADIR.fullPath + "/" + res[i];
console.log("downloading crap to " + dlPath);
ft.download("http://mllsdemode.be/EMM-test/" + escape(res[i]), dlPath, function(e){
console.log("Successful download of "+e.fullPath);
}, onError);
            }
        }
    }
    $("#status").html("");
}, "json");
}

function init() {
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, true);
}
```

At this moment the files only get downloaded when there's nothing in the map be.emm.mobile. I want to download files everytime the app is active and there's internet connection. I also want to delete the files that aren't being used. In the Phonegap documentation they give this example, but I don't know how to implement it.

```
function success(entry) {
console.log("Removal succeeded");
}

function fail(error) {
alert('Error removing file: ' + error.code);
}

// remove the file
entry.remove(success, fail);
```

Anyone who has any tips or advice for me how to handle this?

Comment: Okay, I've managed to find a solution for the update part. Just delete if (knownfiles.indexOf(res[i]) == -1) {} and the files will get downloaded every time there's connection to internet.